# How do I splice into a list outside of a macro in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Say I have a function foo:

`(defun foo (x y &rest args)
  ...)`

And I later want to wrap it with a function bar:

`(defun bar (x &rest args)
    (foo x 100 args))`

Assume bar was then called like this: `(bar 50 1 2 3)`

With this setup, args is a list within the body of bar that holds the trailing parameters, so when I pass it to foo, instead of getting the equivalent of `(foo 50 100 1 2 3)` I of course get `(foo 50 100 '(1 2 3))`. If these were macros, I would use ``(foo ,x 100 ,@args)` within the body of bar to splice args into the function call. ,@ only works inside a backtick-quoted list, however.

How can I do this same sort of splicing within a regular function?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

APPLY will call its first argument with its subsequent arguments, and the last argument must be a list. So:

```
(apply #'foo x 100 args)
```

Comment: +1: You saved my day! Or, at least, you saved me from hacking a very ugly solution.

Comment: I ran into this problem today, apply doesn't work because the "function" I wanted to apply is and, which is actually a macro!

Answer (score 1):

This method is slow, but it may be what you're looking for.

Backquotes, commas, and comma-ats aren't only for macros.  They can also be used in functions if you use eval too.  Again, this is not fast or efficient.  At any rate, here it is:

```
(defun bar (x &rest args)
  (eval `(foo ,x 100 ,@args)))
```

Comment: If you're forced to use eval, then you aren't using some easier and clearer method. Your method was first that came in my head, but I wanted something better. My case was more complicated, but apply with append/concatenate 'list will do the trick.